# Jruby rspec to be run parallely

Tags: ruby-on-rails, optimization, rspec, jruby

Is there something like Spork for Jruby too? We want to parallelize our specs to run faster and pre-load the classes while running the rake task; however we have not been able to do so.

Since our project is considerable in size, specs take about 15 minutes to complete and this poses a serious challenge to quick turnaround.

Any ideas are more than welcome.

Cheers

Comment: How did you solve your issue at the end?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try specjour, a system to distribute your test on several server.

http://github.com/sandro/specjour